# How to do word break in Ascii Doc?

Tags: text, ascii, overlapping, asciidoc

I am writing documentation in Ascii Doc style (AsciiDocFX GUI, but I suppose it is invalid to topic) and I am having a problem.

When I create a table and then **input a long word with no spaces inside of cell**, the word is not split into multiple lines, it is overlapping cell next to it.

Is there some way how to fix this problem?

Here is source code from ascii doc

```
[[EXAMPLE_TABLE]]
[cols="4,3,5,7",width="100%",options="header","autowidth"]
|============================
s|Function s| Parameter s| Value                        s| Description
.3+^.^|toLongWorddddddddddd  |Command         |AnotherLongWord     |Some description with spaces
|Parameter   |Value                      |...
|Parameter   |Value                      |...
|============================
```

Here is the output (image snipped from exported pdf file):

[image]

Final goal is simple - to have nice-looking table.

---

Note:

When I export this document to html file, the table is fine, but it is not able to be printed out properly. I need the pdf for management..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short,

I asked a guy who is working with AsciiDoc for a year and he said, that it is simply not possible. AsciiDoc framework doesn't support this possibility.

The only solution is to split the long word into multiple smaller words by spaces. :(

Answer (score 0):

I use zero-width space to do the job (​). At the very least they are invisible.

But be aware: it can obstruct text search for these long words if the search engine is not clever enough. And anyone copying them might end up contaminating their own text with invisible characters =).